Conical hanukiah candle wells
Why do so many hanukiot have conical candle wells?  They don't hold the candles, and when they do, they do so precariously.  Is there a reason for building them that way?  I gave up on my main one, a beautiful one which I bought in Tzfat, and my main one is now one with cylindrical wells, bought in Jerusalem.
Note: To those who want to close because not about Judaism.  I asked for a reason.  If the reason is halachic, then the matter is very much about Judaism.  If it is not, it's not.
New note. Chabad has the right idea.  The hanukiot they give out have beautiful deep cylindrical candle wells.

Most skrews leave conical holes. Sounds like a Chinese cost optimization.

Were they meant to hold oil?

There is no significance to the Menorah except for practicality and  Hiddur Mitzvah, so no halachic reason.

If the reason is halachic, then the matter is very much about Judaism. Why would you think it's halachic?
